# Export a excel file from a location using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an excel file on my c drive in a folder.Now i want to export/open it from jquery/javascript.
Please help me out.

Comment: In my view we can not access the machine drives in javascript or jquery.

Comment: Can you provide more details? I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Googleing javascript and excel I'm finding some things that might work in IE only, but if you need cross browser support it doesn't sound possible.

Comment: I am creating and savingn file using a webmethod and cakking that web method using ajax.When it success i want to open that file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. For security reasons, it is not possible to access the file system with javascript.

If it was possible, it would be easy for a malicious web page to steal your files.

Comment: Yes u r right.Can i use responce object in webmoth to export a excel file,c#

Comment: I don't know about webmoth (never heard of it), but in normal asp.net, it is no problem to save binary data to the responce. Use google, there are tons of examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can open it using javascript or jQuery.

Perhaps you should look at uploading the file using a file upload control. Then you can use the file once it has been uploaded.

Have a look at this for the "how" side of things
-> http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Answer (score 0):

In my view we can not access the machine drives in javascript or jquery.

Write some java/c# code in servlet to convert it into binary stream.

Then in you html use iframe or object to display it